# Динамические контролы (TextBox)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-basic

У меня создаются по нажатию на кнопку контролы, два TextBox
Вопрос: как мне получить значение нужного контрола?
Если допустим, они создаются и у каждого индивидуальное название типо

- CheckBox1
- CheckBox2
- CheckBox3
- и т.д.

Как получить Text с обычного CheckBox я знаю, но тут идёт речь идёт о динамических контролах.
Пример кода

```
Dim enter1 As New CheckBox
With enter1
   .Top = pos_enter
   .Left = 458
   .Name = "CheckBox" & count_stringbind
End With
Me.Controls.Add(enter1)
AddHandler enter1.CheckedChanged, AddressOf enter_checked

Sub enter_checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
'пусто'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub enter_checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Dim enter1 As CheckBox = CType(sender, CheckBox)
  // enter1.Text
  // enter1.Checked
End Sub
```